# Why can you not downvote comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, downvoting

You can up and downvote posts, but why can you only upvote comments? What is the thinking for not allow any sort of downvote on comments (not that I am saying that you should lose or gain rep from votes on comments)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[See extensive discussion on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3615/270345). Quoting the Jon Skeet:

> If a comment is wrong, respond to it with another comment. That provides a lot more information than a downvote which could mean anything.

---

If you want to debate this, take it to Meta SE.

Comment: No, I agree. :)